Pearsons Correlation more than one Variable
I have a question about the correlations (stats)
I would like to know how the presentation assessments of students correlate to those of experts.
30 students and 3 experts evaluated a presentation based on 10 criteria. I would now like to measure the general correlation of the assessments. My idea was to prepare the data in this way.




Mean Students
Mean Experts




Voice
3.4
4.5


Content
5.4
6.5


xxxx
xxx
xxxx



Can I calculate the correlation this way? My variable 1 would be the mean value of the students and variable 2 the mean value of the experts. But I would integrate the 10 criteria in a correlation calculation.
Or would I have to calculate the correlation for each individual criterion somehow?

This question might have many valid answers, because they depend on how you intend to interpret and use this "correlation" you wish to calculate.  So, please give us a clear description or characterization of it.  //  The last question is mysterious, for what might you mean by an "individual correlation"?

The aim of the study is to validate a rubric. Both groups (students and experts) used the same rubric for the assessment. The aim is to investigate whether the rubric improves the correlation between the assessments (pre-post design)
